# Why is the address of this volatile variable always at 1?

Tags: c++, iostream, implicit-conversion, cout, memory-address

I wanted to inspect the address of my variable

```
volatile int clock;
cout << &clock;
```

But it always says that x is at address 1. Am i doing something wrong??

Comment: *1* need not always represent numerical value -- could be logical as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does std::cout convert volatile pointers to bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501737/why-does-stdcout-convert-volatile-pointers-to-bool)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

iostreams will cast most pointers to `void *` for display - but no conversion exists for `volatile` pointers. As such C++ falls back to the implicit cast to `bool`. Cast to `void*` explicitly if you want to print the address:

```
std::cout << (void*)&clock;
```

Comment: Yes, there is an automatic conversion. It's just that it's automatically converted to `bool`, not `void *`, as C++ does not have automatic conversion to `void *` for pointers (C does, but C++ requires an explicit cast)

Comment: @bdonlan: You've got it backwards. Any normal pointer can be implicitly converted to `void*`, it's `void*` to `T*` that requires a cast.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as it stands.  The conversion of `T*` to `void*` is implicit.

Comment: @bdonlan Sorry, but C++ does have an implicit conversion of `T*` to `void*`.  The answer as written is wrong, or at least incomplete; what C++ doesn't support is implicitly casting away `volatile`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Presumably that's because non-`volatile` pointers to `volatile` objects permit exactly the kind of memory-caching that `volatile` is supposed to prevent?

Comment: In C++ C-style casting should be avoided - this should be changed to `const_cast`.

Answer (score 17):

There's an `operator<<` for `const void*`, but there's no `operator<<` for `volatile void*`, and the implicit conversion will not remove `volatile` (it won't remove `const` either).

As GMan says, the cv-qualification of the type pointed to should be irrelevant to the business of printing an address. Perhaps the overload defined in 27.7.3.6.2 should be `operator<<(const volatile void* val);`, I can't immediately see any disadvantage. But it isn't.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(const void *a) {
    std::cout << "pointer\n";
}

void foo(bool a) {
    std::cout << "bool\n";
}

int main() {
    volatile int x;
    foo(&x);
    std::cout << &x << "\n";
    int y;
    foo(&y);
    std::cout << &y << "\n";
    void foo(volatile void*);
    foo(&x);
}

void foo(volatile void *a) {
    std::cout << "now it's a pointer\n";
}
```

Output:

```
bool
1
pointer
0x22cd28
now it's a pointer
```

Comment: Beat me by literally one second, urg :(. To add on: in the solution proposed by bdonlan, the c-style cast as a `const_cast`. For the purpose of printing, it's not really a concern.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no overload for `operator <<` that takes a pointer to `volatile`, and there is no pointer conversion that could satisfy it.

According to C++ standard,

> for any type `T`, pointer to `T`, pointer to `const T`, and pointer to `volatile T` are considered distinct parameter types, as are reference to `T`, reference to `const T`, and reference to `volatile T`.

[Operator `<<` has no overload for pointers to non-static member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), pointers to volatile, or function pointers, so attempting to output such objects invokes implicit conversion to `bool`.