# Why does the compiler force this conversion below into a bool value?

Tags: c++, c++14, static-cast

I'm testing [expr.static.cast]/2 with the following snippet (see [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d394331e665e755d)):

```
#include <iostream>
struct B{ int i = 2; };
struct D: public B{};
int main()
{
    D d;
    std::cout << &d << '\n';
    std::cout << &(static_cast<D&>((B&)d)) << '\n';
    std::cout << &(static_cast<const D&>((B&)d)) << '\n';
    std::cout << &(static_cast<const volatile D&>((B&)d)) << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
0x7fff65a8f6d0
0x7fff65a8f6d0
0x7fff65a8f6d0
1
```

With the following warning in gcc:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:13:57: warning: the address of 'd' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]
     std::cout << &(static_cast<const volatile D&>((B&)d)) << '\n';
```

Why does the compiler force the last conversion below into a bool value?

Comment: Funny expermient : making `d` `volatile` also yields `true` for `&d`.

Comment: To avoid forcing people to click on the link, please copy the warning and the runtime output into the question.

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239262/why-is-the-address-of-this-volatile-variable-always-at-1). There is simply no conversion for volatile pointers.