# Why does ostream prints `1` for a string defined as `volatile char[]`?

Tags: c++, string, printf, iostream, volatile

Consider this (artificial) example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  volatile char test[] = "abc";
  std::printf("%s\n", test);
  std::cout << test << "\n";
}
```

Compiling it with GCC and running gives the following output:

```
$ g++ test.cc 
$ ./a.out 
abc
1
```

As you can see `printf` prints the string correctly while `cout` prints `1`. Why does writing to `cout` produces `1` in this case?

Comment: `volatile char[N]` matches `bool` better than `const char *`. Actually, it doesn't match `const char *` at all.

Comment: @sharth great catch, I did not even think to look for a dup. They are close enough they may make a good merge.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only suitable overload of `operator<<` is that for `bool`, so the array is converted (via a pointer) to `bool`, giving `true` since its address is non-null. This outputs as `1` unless you use the `std::boolalpha` manipulator.

It can't use the overload for `const char *` which would output the string, or that for `const void *` which would output the pointer value, since those conversions would require removing the `volatile` qualifier. Implicit pointer conversions can add qualifiers, but can't remove them.

To output the string, you'd have to cast away the qualifier:

```
std::cout << const_cast<const char*>(test) << "\n";
```

but beware that this gives undefined behaviour since the array will be accessed as if it were not volatile.

`printf` is an old-school variadic function, giving no type safety. The `%s` specifier makes it interpret the argument as `const char *`, whatever it actually is.

Comment: Is this technically legal? Can `operator<<` optimize on the assumption that the string is not volatile? For example, it might do `strlen(s)` to decide how big a buffer to allocate, then use `strcpy` to copy to that buffer.

Comment: The answers with casts have undefined behavior: C++14[dcl.type.cv]p6 says "If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through the use of a glvalue with a non-volatile-qualified type, the program behavior is undefined." You can generally only interact with volatile arrays through hand-written loops over the elements.

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin I was wondering about this but `const_cast` in this case yields a `prvalue` as far as I can tell but I am have not thought about in detail yet.

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin but I removed it from my answer until I can determine for sure.

Comment: @RaymondChen: If the characters in the string are changing underneath the print, you're lost anyway: the end of the string could move earlier than the current point in the iteration.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: The `const_cast` does yield a prvalue `const char*` pointing to the first element of the volatile array ([expr.const.cast]). But that just means that the _pointer_ is an rvalue, not anything it points to. Dereferencing that pointer yields an lvalue referring to that first element ([expr.unary.op]), which gives undefined behavior.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Yes, you're right, it would give undefined behaviour. I've added a warning.

Answer (score 5):

The [std::basic_ostream::operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) only has an overload for `const char*` or `const void*` which does not match in this case since you can not discard the *volatile* qualifier without a cast, this is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `4.4` *Qualification conversions* which says:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 T” can be converted to a prvalue of
>   type “pointer to cv2 T” if “cv2 T” is more cv-qualified than “cv1 T”.

so it is using the `bool` version and since it is not a `nullptr` the result is `true`.

If you remove the *volatile* qualifier from `test` this will provide the result you expect. Several answers suggest using a `const_cast` to remove the volatile qualifiers but this is undefined behavior. We can see by going to section `7.1.6.1` *The cv-qualifiers* paragraph *6* which says:

> If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a
>   volatile-qualified type through the use of a glvalue with a
>   non-volatile-qualified type, the program behavior is undefined.

`const_cast` in this case yields a *prvalue* but dereferencing that pointer yields an *lvalue* which will invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Answer found [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/329452/volatile-string-why-has-1-output) by a minimal amount of web searching:

> Short answer: `cout` is interpreting the object as a `bool` due to the `volatile` qualifier. It's a quirk of overloading for the `<<` operator.
>
> Long answer: A volatile pointer can't be converted to a non-volatile pointer without an explicit cast, so neither the `char*` nor the `void*` overload can be used when the `<<` operator is called. There's no volatile qualified overload, and the closest match is the `bool` overload, thus your array is interpreted as a boolean value rather than an address or a string.
>
> You can fix it a number of ways, but an explicit cast is probably what you wanted:

```
std::cout<< (char*)test <<std::endl;
```

(Personally I would cast to `const char*`.)

Answer (score 0):

It's the `volatile` qualifier that casts it to a `bool`, try instead:

```
std::cout << const_cast<char*>(test) << "\n";
```

Comment: This answer has undefined behavior: C++14[dcl.type.cv]p6 says "If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through the use of a glvalue with a non-volatile-qualified type, the program behavior is undefined."

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin guess the variable's quite... `volatile`! ;)